# dbms_datapump.get_dumpfile_info can't read directory when compiled in stored procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, directory, datapump

I'm creating a stored procedure to load (impdp) a Datapump database dump.

I am trying to get the dump file's creation date (to compare with the date of a previously loaded dump), using DBMS_DATAPUMP.GET_DUMPFILE_INFO, [like in this example](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-5AAC848B-5A2B-4FD1-97ED-D3A048263118.htm#SUTIL977).

When running in an anonymous block (like below), it runs fine, outputting the dump file's creation date. However, when this same block is adapted and compiled in a stored procedure, I get the ORA-39087 error (Directory name is invalid).

```
DECLARE 
  dumpfile VARCHAR2(256) := 'my_file.dp';
  dir VARCHAR2(30) := 'MY_DIR';
  info ku$_dumpfile_info;
  ft NUMBER;
BEGIN
  sys.dbms_datapump.get_dumpfile_info(dumpfile, dir, info, ft);
  FOR rec IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE (info) WHERE item_code = 6 ) LOOP 
    dbms_output.put_line(rec.value);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

The directory exists. The name is valid. When I run

```
SELECT * FROM datapump_dir_objs;
```

with the same user, I can see that the user has READ and WRITE privileges on the directory. Oracle version is 11g Release 11.2.0.4.0.

Any light on what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the user have read and write privileges granted directly to them, or via a role? (A quick way to check is to see whether your query still shows the same data after you do `set role none`.)

Comment: Thanks @AlexPoole !
The privilege is granted by a role. I added `AUTHID CURRENT_USER` to the procedure's header and all went fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the READ and WRITE privileges on the directory were added via a role. By default, anonymous blocks are executed with the current user's privileges, but stored procedures are not.

I added `AUTHID CURRENT_USER` to the procedure's header and managed to access my directory.

Thanks to Alex Poole for the insight.